# Sequelize - avoid deleting rows of many-to-many association when inserting a new one

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

My problem is that when I execute this code:

```
const task = await db.tasks.findByPk(1)
const user = await db.users.findByPk(4)
await user.setTasks(task)
```

This happens:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `tasks`.`id`, `tasks`.`start_date` FROM `tasks` AS `tasks` WHERE `tasks`.`id` = '1';
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `name`, `surname`, `email`, `role` FROM `users` AS `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = '4';
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `task_id`, `user_id` FROM `users_tasks` AS `users_tasks` WHERE `users_tasks`.`user_id` = 4;
Executing (default): DELETE FROM `users_tasks` WHERE `user_id` = 4 AND `task_id` IN (2)
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `users_tasks` (`id`,`task_id`,`user_id`) VALUES (NULL,1,4);
```

The user with id 4 had a previous association with a task with id 2. The issue is, I want to keep that association! It is perfectly fine for the purpose of my application for a user to be assigned to more tasks (and vice versa).

I would actually say that that's the normal desired behaviour of a many-to-many relationship... why is Sequelize deleting the row on `users_tasks` before adding a new one, and how can I prevent this from happening?

Here is my user model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var User = sequelize.define('users', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        },
        surname: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(256),
            allowNull: false
        },
    }, {
        tableName: 'users',
        timestamps: false,
    })

    User.associate = function (models) {
        User.belongsToMany(models.tasks, {through: 'users_tasks', foreignKey: 'user_id'})
    }

    return User
}
```

Here is my task model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Task = sequelize.define('tasks', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        start_date: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: true,
        },
    }, {
        tableName: 'tasks',
        timestamps: false
    })

    Task.associate = function (models) {
        Task.belongsToMany(models.users, {through: 'users_tasks', foreignKey: 'task_id'})
    }

    return Task
}
```

And here is my join table:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('users_tasks', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        task_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'tasks',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'users',
                key: 'id'
            }
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'users_tasks',
        timestamps: false
    })
}
```

Do I need to change something on the models definitions, or do I need to change something in the way I call `setTasks`? Or else, what do I need to do? Why is Sequelize enforcing this weird and unwanted behaviour of deleting previously existing associations?

Comment: By default 'set' removes any existing association and adds the one that is being passed. I think if you want to maintain the existing ones you probably use 'add' function. Which won't remove the existing association and add new ones. But remember if there are any composite unique contraints in target table and you try to add a duplicate values, db will throw you unique contraint voilation error.

Comment: @GhulamMohammedTaher yes! That was the problem! I replaced `setJams` with `addJams` and now the `DELETE` doesn't get executed anymore. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I will be glad to accept it as the correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I should be using `add` instead of `set` if I want to keep the preexisting relations.

So, the correct way of achieving the result I want is this:

```
const task = await db.tasks.findByPk(1)
const user = await db.users.findByPk(4)
await user.addTasks(task)
```